# Is the default logging to File and Console in Dropwizard use AsyncAppender?

Tags: log4j, dropwizard, asyncappender

In my DW app I am trying to make the logging to the file and console asynchronous. I found that I can use the AsyncAppender, but is that already configured in DropWizard or do I need to enable it, if so how do I configure the logger to use the AsyncAppender

```
Logger root = (Logger)   LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
AsyncAppender fileAppender = (AsyncAppender) root.getAppender("async-file-appender");
```

My config.yaml is looks like this

```
server:
  minThreads: 512
  type: default
supportedCarParcFile: /opt/foo/my_app/config/my-app.json

logging:  
  appenders:  
    -  
      threshold: INFO  
      type: console  
    -  
      archivedFileCount: 7  
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /opt/foo/my_app/logs/my-app-%d.log.gz  
      currentLogFilename: /opt/foo/my_app/logs/my-app.log  
      threshold: INFO  
      timeZone: CST  
      type: file  
    -  
      archivedFileCount: 7  
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /opt/foo/my_app/logs/my-app_error-%d.log.gz  
      currentLogFilename: /opt/foo/my_app/logs/my-app_error.log  
      threshold: ERROR  
      timeZone: CST  
      type: file  
  loggers:  
    metrics:  
      additive: true  
      appenders:  
        -  
          archivedFileCount: 10  
          archivedLogFilenamePattern: /opt/foo/my_app/logs/metrics-%d.log.gz  
          currentLogFilename: /opt/foo/my_app/logs/metrics.log  
          type: file  
      level: INFO
```

I am using **DropWizard 1.0.5**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DefaultLoggingFactory`](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/dropwizard-logging/apidocs/io/dropwizard/logging/DefaultLoggingFactory.html) in dropwizard is used by default for logging purposes.

Which as [you can see here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging/DefaultLoggingFactory.java#L137) makes use of the [`AsyncLoggingEventAppenderFactory`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging/async/AsyncLoggingEventAppenderFactory.java#L17) using the [`AsyncAppenderBase`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/AsyncAppenderBase.html)
to build the appenders. The documentation of `ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase` states that:

> This appender and derived classes, log events asynchronously. In order
>   to avoid loss of logging events, this appender should be closed. It is
>   the user's responsibility to close appenders, typically at the end of
>   the application lifecycle.
>
> This appender buffers events in a
>   BlockingQueue. Worker thread created by this appender takes events
>   from the head of the queue, and dispatches them to the single appender
>   attached to this appender.

Now to your question, *but is that already configured in DropWizard or do I need to enable it*?

I would say, you don't need to enable it explicitly to configure async appending of the logs. The `AsyncLoggingEventAppenderFactory` shall take care of it.